# reading from txt file and writing in textbox

Tags: vb.net

Can somebody help me with this, im stuck no idea what to do next

give a text file at any location in the computer it contains 15 different integers that can be repeated
make the program so that multiple repetitions of one number are not printed separately, but each number is printed exactly once
and next to it are written in which places he appeared

```
    Imports System.IO
Public Class form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim povratnaVrijednost As DialogResult
        Dim nazivDatoteke As String
        Try
            OpenFileDialog1.AddExtension = True
            OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False
            OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Tekst datoteke (*.txt)|*.txt;"
            povratnaVrijednost = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
            If povratnaVrijednost = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                If OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True And
                OpenFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = True Then
                    nazivDatoteke = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                    TextBox1.Text = nazivDatoteke
                    Dim citac As New StreamReader(nazivDatoteke)
                    Dim redTeksta As String = ""
                    Do
                        redTeksta = citac.ReadLine()
                        If Not redTeksta Is Nothing Then
                            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + redTeksta
                        End If
                    Loop Until redTeksta Is Nothing
                    citac.Close()
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Greska prilikom otvaranja" + ex.StackTrace.ToString)


        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

[123](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbD3H.png)

Comment: You need to actually provide a detailed explanation of the specific problem you have encountered. It's not enough to say "here's my assignment, here's my code" and expect us to take it from there. You need to have debugged your code and be able to explain EXACTLY how and where it's not behaving as expected, and what that expectation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Requirement #1:**

> give a text file at any location in the computer it contains 15 different integers that can be repeated

This requirement implies a couple of other requirements. First, you're expected to read the text file. Second, you're expected to parse the values into numbers (presumably integers).

You can use an OpenFileDialog ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog)) and specify that it can only accept text files:

```vb
Using browseFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    With browseFileDialog
        .Filter = "*.txt|*.txt"

        If (.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok) Then
            '.FileName will be the text file that the user picked
        End If
    End With
End Using
```

To read the text file, assuming you want each line, use the File.ReadAllLines method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines)):

```vb
Using browseFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    With browseFileDialog
        .Filter = "*.txt|*.txt"

        If (.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok) Then
            Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(.FileName)
        End If
    End With
End Using
```

To parse the values, use the Array.ConvertAll method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall)) and inside of the predicate use the Integer.Parse method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse)):

```vb
Using browseFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    With browseFileDialog
        .Filter = "*.txt|*.txt"

        If (.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok) Then
            Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(.FileName)
            Dim values = Array.ConvertAll(lines, Function(line) Integer.Parse(line))
        End If
    End With
End Using
```

Keep in mind that if you wanted to validate that the lines are all valid numbers, instead of assuming that they are, this step would be different. However, you didn't specify that requirement in your original post so I'm not including how to do that.

**Requirement #2:**

> make the program so that multiple repetitions of one number are not printed separately, but each number is printed exactly once

You can use the Random.Next method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next)) to generate random values. Be sure to declare the new instance of the random object once so that the seed is only set once. To randomly order the values, use the OrderBy method ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)) passing the random value in the predicate:

```vb
Private ReadOnly _random As New Random()
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using browseFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
        With browseFileDialog
            .Filter = "*.txt|*.txt"

            If (.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok) Then
                Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(.FileName)
                Dim values = Array.ConvertAll(lines, Function(line) Integer.Parse(line))
                Dim randomlyOrderedValues = values.OrderBy(Function(value) _random.Next())

                RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(", ", randomlyOrderedValues.ToArray())
            End If
        End With
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: When `Integer.Parse` fails an an exception occurs and is not handled. Is this your intent?

Comment: @Mary - I have this in my post: Keep in mind that if you wanted to validate that the lines are all valid numbers, instead of assuming that they are, this step would be different. However, you didn't specify that requirement in your original post so I'm not including how to do that.

Comment: This isn't my post. In that case wouldn't `Function(line) CInt(line)` be easier?

Comment: @Mary - it is more concise, but I don't like to use VB keywords. JMcIlhinney has already gone over why he uses them in certain situations, but I put my head in the ground like a dodo bird.

Comment: "The Visual Basic functions are designed for optimal interaction with Visual Basic code, and they also make your source code shorter and easier to read. " See MS Docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions#remarks

Answer (score 0):

Default for `.AddExtension` is `True`. Default for `.Multiselect` is `False`. I have simplified the `If` statement by comparing the return value of `.Showdialog` directly to the desired `DialogResult`. If the path of file don't exist the dialog will show a waring.

Always scope variables as narrowly as possible. I move the `Dim nazivDatoteke` to inside the If since it is not used anywhere else. `StreamReader`s require a `Using` block since they need to be disposed.

Why a `RichTextBox` for a text file?

As you can see getting the distince items in the array is easy, a single line of code. What is more difficult is finding the indexes in the original array, `lines`.

I looped through all the items in the `distinct` array (actually it is an `IEnumerable(Of String)` but that is not important to this code, it is just easier to type array in my explanation). I created a `List(Of Integer)` to hold the indexes of each item in the original array, `lines`. The `startIndex` where the `FindIndex` method of an `Array` is the location of the first occurrence of the String.

On each iteration of the `Do` loop  I look for the matches to the item from the `lines` array. The `FindIndex` takes parameters (original array, index to start at, what we are looking for). It stops as soon as it finds a match and returns -1 if no matches are found. You can see the operation of this method be setting a break point and checking the variable values.

If a match is found I added that value to the list and change the `startIndex` to the position following the found index.

Next I used a `StringBuilder` to create the string to display. I chose the immediate window for testing purposes but you could show `sb.ToString` in a text box or add it to a `ListBox`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Tekst datoteke (*.txt)|*.txt;"
    If DialogResult.OK = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog Then
        Dim nazivDatoteke = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        TextBox1.Text = nazivDatoteke
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(nazivDatoteke)
        Dim distinct = lines.Distinct
        For Each item In distinct
            Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
            Dim startIndex = Array.IndexOf(lines, item)
            Do
                Dim FoundIndex = Array.FindIndex(lines, startIndex, Function(line) line = item)
                If FoundIndex = -1 Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    lst.Add(FoundIndex)
                    startIndex = FoundIndex + 1
                End If
            Loop
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            sb.Append(item)
            For Each i In lst
                sb.Append($" ({i})")
            Next
            Debug.Print(sb.ToString)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This code displays the distinct items in the list and follow it with the positions (indexes) in the original list.